# I am receiving the Laravel error "MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line x" while trying to POST a query form

Tags: php, forms, laravel, post, laravel-blade

It's just a query form. I searched for this problem and tried the many solutions I found, but none of them solved this problem.

Laravel version: **5.4.23**. Using **Blade** template engine.

**My route:**

```
Route::post('products/search', 'ProductsController@search');
```

**My form:**

```
{{Form::open(['url' => ['products/search']])}}
    {{Form::text('search', $search)}}
    {{Form::submit('Search')}}
{{Form::close()}}
```

**My controller:**

```
class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    ...

    public function search(Request $request) {
        dd('This point is never reached.');
        return view(...
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

I tried to change the route to `Route::get`, but not worked. Tried to change my form method to GET, as `{{Form::open(['method' => 'GET', 'url' => ['products/search']])}}`, with no success.

Comment: do u have any other route in the app?

Answer (score 0):

So the issue might be:

**Solution1**. You have another route defined on top of that, something like: `Route::get('products/{wildcard}', 'Controller'}`  in that case make sure you put all the other routes under the one you're trying to get to work.

**Solution2**

Go ahead and delete the controller. Then run `composer dump-autoload`

Then run the command on command line `php artisan make:controller UserController` then paste profile method that you have.

**Solution3** You might have cached the routes so do: `php artisan route:clear`

**Solution 4**. change url to

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar')) }}
    //
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the framework but why is the `url` value in the form an array?

I would have thought you'd want something like

```
Form::open(['url' => 'products/search'])
```

According to the docs, the default form method is `POST` so you should keep your route as `Route::post`. If you want to change the method to `GET` (which I would recommend for a search action), simply use `Route::get` and

```
Form::open(['url' => 'products/search', 'method' => 'get'])
```

---

Seems you can also use named route names or even controller methods via the `action` property, ie

```
Form::open(['action' => 'ProductsController@search'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change in your blade file like:

```
{{Form::open(['url' => ['products/search']])}}
```

**TO**

```
{{Form::open(['url' => 'products/search'])}}
```

**OR** you can add route name in your route like :

```
Route::post('products/search', 'ProductsController@search')->name('products.search');


{{ Form::open(['route' => 'products.search', 'method' => 'post']) }}
```

Hope this help you